# How to load a partial in a form?

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm currently migrating a toolbox from Zend 1 to Zend2. I'm a newbie in both technologies.

In one form the former toolbox load and handle a template through a decorator.

Example :

```
$this->setDecorators(array(array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => 'forms/exemple-external.phtml'))));
```

My template :

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span10">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="lastname">
                <button id="find-user" class="btn btn-mini" style="margin-right: 20px" type="button"><b>. . .</b></button>
                    Nom
                </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Nom" class="input-medium" value="<?php echo $this->lastname; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--/span-->
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="firstname">Prénom</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Prénom" class="input-medium" value="<?php echo $this->firstname; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--/span-->
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="active_directory_username">Nom LDAP</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="active_directory_username" name="active_directory_username" placeholder="Nom LDAP" class="input-medium" value="<?php echo $this->active_directory_username; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--/span-->
    </div><!--/row-->
</div>
```

How can I mimick this behavior in Zend2 ? This form was used as a subform to another form. So the main goal here is to be able to render this template while rendering the parent form.

Do you have any clue about doing this ?

Comment: Maybe collection is what you want to use [Zend 2 Collections](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html) and in views you can set partial for rendering your collection or just use formRow() method with partial as 4th argument

Comment: I guess I'm gonna use a partial while rendering my form. I was trying to mimick the behavior of the decorator.  But I don't think there is a pratical use to it.  I will use a partial in the toolbox. It seems to be the Zend 2 way.

Comment: Yeah its really i dont have experience in zend 1 so i dont know about decorator much. But formRow() with partial is easy to use :)

Comment: I have to render an entire form as a Row. FormCollection is able to render the form. But I need to control the layout. I mean it is a an inline search form with some Jquery.      I need to use a very specific partial.     So I guess, I should create my own helper or using a partial.

Answer (score 1):

You have option to set partial on collection. I will share my code with you, I think it will boost your time.
In your view:

```
$this->formCollection()->setElementHelper($this->formRow()->setPartial('partial/link-collection'));                   
echo $this->formCollection($addMovieForm->get('links'));
```

and partial/link-collection:

```
<?php if ($this->element instanceof \Zend\Form\Element\Button) : ?>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <?php echo $this->formElement($this->element) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php else : ?>
    <div class="control-group">
        <?php echo $this->formLabel($this->element) ?>
        <div class="controls">
            <?php echo $this->formElement($this->element) ?>
            <?php echo $this->formElementErrors($this->element) ?>
        </div>

    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You got +1 because your idea seems nice. But I still have an issue using it. It works nice if I force partial rendering (by editing framework code then revert it). But by default the partial rendering seem to be ingnored or overwrote. Any ideas ?

Comment: I get it. I'm already using a bootstrap plugin, which does not support partial rendering. I guess I will fork it and add this capability.

Comment: You have partial bootstrap plugin for rendering with helper views for bootstrap in zend 2? gimmeh link plox :) Im curious.

Comment: Last master version support partial, but there is a little more work on css. Here is the link :https://github.com/neilime/zf2-twb-bundle/tree/1.0.   But examples are no longer up to date.